# Geometric algebra from the vector space of $N\times N$ Hermitian matrices

Tags: matrices, quantum-mechanics, clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras, hermitian-matrices

I am a physicist working in quantum mechanics, and I am trying to learn geometric algebra in order to get a different perspective on the same thing.

In particular, I am interested in the possibility of generating a geometric algebra from the real vector space of $N \times N$ Hermitian matrices, in such a way that the matrix product plays the role of the geometric product. I'm aware that in the $2\times 2$ case, the anticommutation rules of the Pauli matrices are equivalent to the generating condition of a geometric algebra, so the algebra can be constructed from those three vectors. Is it possible to extend this idea to any arbitrary dimension? Specifically, I want to know if I can consider quantum observables (which can be represented by Hermitian matrices) as vectors in some geometric algebra. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean realizing the geometric algebra (= Clifford algebra) concretely using matrices, so that each element of the algebra corresponds to a matrix in such a way that multiplication is respected? If so, maybe the [classification of Clifford algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_Clifford_algebras#Classification) is what you're looking for? Depending on the dimension and signature of the space you start with, you get real, complex or quaternionic matrices, whose size is some power of two.

Comment: Not exactly, @Hans. Considering the real vector space of  $N\times N$ Hermitian matrices with the product $\langle A,B\rangle =\text{tr}(BA)$, I wonder if it is possible to choose some elements of this space and construct a geometric algebra such that the geometric product coincides with the matrix product. Additionally, every Hermitian matrix should be an element of this algebra (possibly a vector plus a scalar part). I suspect that the limitation may be the contraction axiom: in $N=2$ everything works because the square of every vector  (linear combination of Pauli matrices) is a scalar.